# How many alien races have a name in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

In Dragon Ball many races have a name, for example,

- Humans
- Saiyans
- Namekians
- Tsufurus
- Yardrats
- Frost demons
- Metamorans

How many other alien races are mentioned/ have a name in Dragon Ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of races is rather extremely huge, so please do have a look at [the wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_races) which sums most of them up. Do note that "humans" are referred to as "earthlings".

A few major common ones are:

- Android
- Angel
- Demon
- Demon Realm race
- Dragon
- Earthling
- Frieza race
- Majin
- Namekian
- Saiyan
- Shinjin
- Tuffle